# What are the minimal and maximal ellipsoids for a convex set of quantum-information-theoretic interest?

Tags: python, matrix, optimization, physics, computational-geometry

A famous theorem [JohnEllipsoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_ellipsoid) of Fritz John informs us that associated with a convex body are unique circumscribed and inscribed ellipsoids of minimal and maximal volumes.

Now, a body--argued to be convex in the answer of Nathaniel Johnston to [SpectraConvexity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376200/is-the-set-of-two-qubit-absolutely-separable-states-convex-and-if-so-what-are)--is the three-dimensional set of ordered spectra of absolutely separable two-qubit states [Adhikari](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.00891). (The two-qubit states themselves comprise the 15-dimensional convex set of 4 x 4 Hermitian, nonnegative definite trace 1 matrices.) This three-dimensional set of four eigenvalues (summing to 1) is defined by the constraint

```
1 > x && x >= y && y >= z && z >= 1 - x - y - z >= 0 && 
 x - z < 2 Sqrt[y (1 - x - y - z)
```

(The area/volume ratio of this set has been shown to equal 6 [AreaVolumeRatio](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234792/verify-a-conjectured-formula-for-a-modification-of-a-3d-constrained-integration) .)

The Mosek python code [DominicSuggestion](https://docs.mosek.com/9.2/pythonfusion/case-studies-ellipsoids.html)
entitled "Inner and outer Löwner-John Ellipsoids" has been brought to my attention
by "Dominic" in his comment on his answer to the question [JohnEllipsoids](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/graph-construct-john-ellipsoids-circumscribing-and-inscribing-a-certain-3d-con) .

The code appears to require an input matrix P--its determinant being computed.

For the problem in which I am interested-two possible forms-indicated in [JohnEllipsoids](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/graph-construct-john-ellipsoids-circumscribing-and-inscribing-a-certain-3d-con)--of P suggest themselves, one (2 x 2) being (in Mathematica notation--since I am not a python user)

P=   {{2 (1 - x - y - z), -x + z}, {-x + z, 2 y}}

and the other (6 x 6)

P =   {{2 (1 - x - y - z), -x + z, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {-x + z, 2 y, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1 - x, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, x - y, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, y - z, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 + x + y + 2 z}} .

If the indicated python code is evaluated  with each input does it lead to an actual solution to the stated problem?

The positive-semidefinitness condition

```
x >= y && y >= z && x + y + 2 z >= 1 && x < z + 2 Sqrt[-y (-1 + x + y + z)]
```

for the 6 x 6 matrix is the constraint noted above that defines the convex set for which we want to find circumscribing and inscribing ellipsoids of minimal and maximal volumes, respectively, while the condition for the 2 x 2 matrix is the sub constraint

x < z + 2 Sqrt[-y (-1 + x + y + z)] .

So, are the indicated 2 x 2 and/or 6 x 6 matrices the appropriate ones to employ in this John ellipsoid framework.

Here is a graphic representation--courtesy of Dominic in his answer to [JohnEllipsoids](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/graph-construct-john-ellipsoids-circumscribing-and-inscribing-a-certain-3d-con)--of the convex set for which we desire to find the two John ellipsoids.

[ConvexSetPolytope?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSvis.jpg)

Perhaps this constitutes evidence in of itself that the set is not a polytope, so the Mosek code needs some modification--as Michal Adamaszek points out in his comment.

Comment: Since this is so highly conceptual and has almost no focus on code, maybe StackOverflow isn't the best place to get the kind of answer you're looking for?

Comment: Well, Random Davis--the question concerns the proper interpretation/implementation of the Mosek python code.

Comment: The Mosek code is intended for the ellipsoid inscribed in a polytope P. If P is convex but not a polytope than it may or may not be possible, depending on if you can rewrite the "for all u" part into something more manageable. It seems that your set has an SDP  representation, so at the very least you can get an approximation by sampling sufficiently many u and constraining the corresponding Cu+d to lie in P.

Comment: Thanks very, very much Michal Adamaszek--exactly the expertise I was hoping to obtain through posing the question. Since I'm not a python user, I may have to struggle some more with implementing your suggested approach. At this point, Ihave no firm knowledge as to whether or not P is a polytope--I would suspect that was "too good to be true". Again, within my limited understanding, whether or nor P is a polytope is itself a challenging question.